# Windows 10 and Outlook 2013 - links inside message don't open in browser

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've just upgraded my Windows 7 Pro 64-bit to the all-new Windows 10 (final version, downloaded directly from Microsoft).
In general, almost everything went through surprisingly well.

But, now when I have a link inside an email message, nothing happens when I click on it. No error messages, but it doesn't get opened in the browser.

I have already done everything there is to do about default programs, setting the wanted browser (Firefox, in this case) as the default one and so on, going over the settings from both Outlook and the browser, but so far nothing seems to solve this weird issue.

I should mention that the content IS indeed identified as a link by Outlook, because I do get the little "hand" mouse cursor when I go over it, and it does show me the related context menu on right-click ("Go to link", "Copy link"...). And it's not an issue of a specific message/sender/content, because it's the same behavior in all of the messages (AND, it was working perfectly fine on Windows 7 before the upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation of the matter, I have come to realize that actually this is not an Outlook issue at all, but a problem with getting Firefox to be the default browser on Windows 10.
I will issue another question in this matter.